# .split gives empty elements in list when chaining .replace methods

Tags: python, replace, split

I am new to Python and am working to take a paragraph and break down the number of words inside of each sentence and then getting the avg word count per sentence.  Before I can do that math, I realized I needed to clean up the data to be able to get into the individual words for each sentence.

I am chaining `.replace()` methods of a paragraph to get the individual sentences and when I `.split()` on the "." I am getting an extra empty string element at the end, making my sentence count 16 instead of 15(the correct result).

Thank you for your help!!

I have found some links that describe the normal whitespace `split` issues, and the new line `split` options, but that doesn't help either as it is not a new line issue?

```py
def get_average_sentence_length(text):
    sentences_in_text = []
    text = text.replace("?", ".").replace("!", ".").replace(",", " ").split(".")
    sentences_in_text = text
    return sentences_in_text

print(get_average_sentence_length(TEXT))
```

You can see the final element is ''.  I have truncated the rest of the paragraph for brevity's sake.

['..., ' I cannot wait to enjoy being on A Brand New Jay', ' It certainly seems like a grand time to explore life and love', '']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` treats a trailing separator as preceding an empty field:

```
>>> text = "foo.bar."
>>> text.split(".")
['foo', 'bar', '']
```

If you want to avoid that, remove the trailing separator:

```
>>> text.rstrip(".").split(".")
['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!!  Both of these answers fixed my issue and taught me some things :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sentences_in_text = text
```

Replace this with:

```
sentences_in_text = [t for t in text if t]
```

So that you filter out those `""` empty strings

Comment: Thank you for your help!!  Both of these answers fixed my issue and taught me some things :)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter before returning the result. Like this

```
def get_average_sentence_length(text):
    sentences_in_text = text.replace("?", ".").replace("!", ".").replace(",", " ").split(".")
    return list(filter(None, sentences_in_text))

print(get_average_sentence_length('some? text. hello!'))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!!  This is another way I was not aware of to fix this.  :)